# Skip Update of Table when no records present-SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZQvLK.jpg)I want to migrate data from old table (table_old) to new table (table_new).

table_old has following columns.

- recordseq
- startdate
- enddate
- field1
- field2
- field3
- recordnum

table_new has following columns.

- recordseq
- startdate
- enddate
- field1
- field2
- field3
- field4
- field5
- field6
- recordnum
- recordnum_old

Each `recordseq` can have multiple records which can be found out by `recordnum` for example:
If for a particular `recordseq` has two records, then 1 and 2 will be present in `recordnum` column data.

Requirement is while migrating the data, every two records in old table should appear in 1 record.

Here data migration means consider `field1`, `field2`, `field3` and `recordnum`.

For example, if a particular seq has 4 records in old table then first record will be inserted in 1st row of new table in `field1`, `field2`, `field3` and 2nd row data will be inserted into `field4`, `field5` and `field6`.

Similarly for 3rd row data in old table will be inserted in 2nd row of new table in `field1`, `field2` and `field3` and 4th row data will be inserted into `field4`, `field5` and `field6` of 2nd row in new table.

Some recordseqs may have only one record. Different seqs may have different recordnums.

In new table  recordnum _old  will hold the recordnum  column data of old table and recordnum  will contain new record number after migrating.

So while migrating first we have inserted recordseq, startdate, enddate and recordnum _old  data
And recordnum be constant number like 999 which will be later updated to actual recordnum.
After this we wrote below code to migrate remain data those are field1,field2, field3 as explained above.

```
    Do
    Begin 
     DECLARE MAX_REC INT;
     DECLARE REC_IDX  INT;

     Select max(recordnum) into MAX_REC FROM table _old;
     MAX_REC := 0;
     REC_IDX:=0;


     while(REC_IDX<= MAX_REC)
     Do
      Begin
      IF(mod(REC_IDX,2)=0) 
       Then

         Update table_new a set (a. recordNum,a.field1,a.field2,a.field3)
         = (select cast(REC_IDX/2 as int),b. field1,b.field2,b.field3 from table_old  b Where 
         a.recordseq=b.recordseq and a.startdate=b.startdate and a.enddate = b.enddate and 
         b.recordnum=REC_IDX)  from table_new a where a.recordnum_old= cast(REC_IDX/2 as int);

      ELSEIF
      THEN
        Update table_new a set (a. recordNum,a.field4,a.field5,a.field6)
        = (select cast(REC_IDX/2 as int),b. field1,b.field2,b.field3 from table_old  b Where 
        a.recordseq=b.recordseq and a.startdate=b.startdate and a.enddate = b.enddate and 
        b.recordnum=REC_IDX)  from table_new a where a.recordnum_old= cast(REC_IDX/2 as int);

     END IF
```

once execution is finished new records can be filtered out by checking records which dont have pagenum 999

Main Issue with this code is if a particual seq has only one record and Max record number in old table is 5 
On first iteration first row of the old record is inserting to first row of new table with rownumber as 1 then  null value is overriding for recordnum in 2nd  iteration as there are no more records present for this record seq.

So I don’t want to update the new table for a seq which has no more records in old table while iterating through while loop.

Can you please help me to achive this.

Comment: Can you illustrate your situation and problem with some data?

Comment: @Isaac I have attached data image.When the record count for particular seq (marked in red-in image)is less than max record count of the table then that seq page number is updating to null as iteration is going on there are no records present for that Seq.So I want to skip the execution of update statement for it.

Comment: `begin .. declare ..; declare ...;` is invalid PL/SQL. And there is no `do` in PL/SQL either. Are you sure you are using Oracle's PL/SQL?